# Command that changes its definition the nth time it's used

Tags: counters, expansion, expl3

I need a command to behave differently the first time than the next times it's called. Right now I use `\newcommand\foo{First\gdef\foo{Next}}`, that is, it redefines itself the first time.

Moreover, I need to “reset” its meaning at some point, so I define `\newcommand\resetfoo{\gdef\foo{First\gdef\foo{Next}}}`.

But this seems to me rather difficult. May be there is an usual way of doing this, but I'm not aware of it (also, I know almost nothing about *expansion*). Which is the correct way of solving this kind of problem?

#### Question

As the question states, I need a more general way: some function to change its definition in its *n* th “expansion” (I'm not sure I'm using the word in the right place). How would you solve this problem? I also need the necessary `\resetfoo`.

In case it's not already done in some way, my idea is to have some command `\changedefinitionafter\foo{3}{OneTwoThree}{Next}` or something like that. `expl3` solution is also welcome.

Here is a more general MWE.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newcommand\foo{First\gdef\foo{Next}}
\newcommand\resetfoo{\gdef\foo{First\gdef\foo{Next}}}

\begin{document}

\foo~\foo~\foo
\resetfoo~\foo~\foo

\end{document}
```

Also, tags and suggestions for the title of the question are welcome.

Comment: I'd define a counter which is increased every time the command is used. In the definition of the command you can then switch the meaning if you check the value of the counter before.

Comment: That's an approach I didn't think of. I'm still not pleased with the idea that the command “carries” all that checking with him, so I will probably make it just redefine itself when the counter reaches some value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{testcount}

\newcommand{\modifyme}{%
\addtocounter{testcount}{1}
\ifnum\thetestcount<3%
    Hello 
\fi
\ifnum\thetestcount>2%
    World
\fi
}

\newcommand{\resetme}{\setcounter{testcount}{0}}

\begin{document}

\modifyme

\modifyme

\modifyme

\modifyme

\resetme

\modifyme

\end{document}
```

[image: Updated example]

Comment: Could you add the `\resetfoo` to answer the question? I guess it's only a `\setcounter{…}{0}` but the idea is that future readers find it. I'm going to accept this answer.

Comment: I just added the `\resetme` command.

Answer (score 9):

I love using counters! Here only the expansion after the number specified in `\changedefinitionafter` is modified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\makeatletter
\newcount\count@foo
\newcount\nth@foo
\newcommand\changedefinitionafter[4]{
    % #1: name of macro
    % #2: exceptional occurence
    % #3: normal expansion
    % #4: exceptional expansion
    \global\count@foo=0
    \global\nth@foo=#2
    \gdef#1{%
        \advance\count@foo by 1
        \ifnum\count@foo=\nth@foo
            #4%
        \else
            #3%
        \fi
    }
    \edef\resetname{reset\expandafter\@gobble\string#1}
    \expandafter\gdef\csname \resetname \endcsname{\global\count@foo=0 }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\obeylines
\changedefinitionafter\foo{3}{OneTwoThree}{Next}
\foo
\foo
\foo
\foo
\resetfoo
\foo
\foo
\foo
\foo
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 6):

No counter, but three macros for each command of this type:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newchangingcommand}[4]{%
  % #1 = macro name
  % #2 = steps
  % #3 = value until step #1
  % #4 = value from step #1
  \@namedef{\string#1@counter}{0}%
  \@namedef{\string#1@limit}{#2}%
  \def#1{%
     % step the counter
     \global\@nameedef{\string#1@counter}{\number\numexpr\@nameuse{\string#1@counter}+1\relax}%
     \ifnum\@nameuse{\string#1@counter}=\@nameuse{\string#1@limit}\relax
       \gdef#1{#4}#4%
     \else
       #3%
     \fi
  }%
}
\providecommand\@nameedef[1]{\expandafter\edef\csname#1\endcsname}
\makeatother

\newchangingcommand{\foo}{3}{Two}{Next}
\newchangingcommand{\foob}{2}{One}{Next}

\begin{document}

\foo--\foob\par
\foo--\foob\par
\foo--\foob\par
\foo--\foob\par

\end{document}
```

[image]

Be aware that using such commands in moving arguments will fail for several reasons.

Comment: Is there any clear benefit in this system versus the “counters system”?